# Incrementally adds one to a list of indices given positions of specified item in list

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, indices

Given a list of tokens, input:

```
>>> tokenized_text = "[CLS] my dog is cute [SEP] he likes slack ##ing [SEP]".split()
>>> tokenized_text 
['[CLS]', 'my', 'dog', 'is', 'cute', '[SEP]', 'he', 'likes', 'slack', '##ing', '[SEP]']
```

The goal is to create an index for up till every `[SEP]` from left to right, find the `[SEP]` tokens and then incrementally adds the 1 after every `[SEP]`, so the desired output indices for the `tokenize_text` list above is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I've tried:

```
# Find the indices of `[SEP]`.
>>> sep_indices = np.array(np.where(np.array(tokenized_text) == "[SEP]"))[0]
>>> sep_indices
array([ 5, 10])

>>> prev = 0
>>> out =[]
>>> for i, idx in enumerate(sep_indices):
...     for _ in range(idx-prev):
...         out.append(i)
...     prev = idx
... 
>>> out = [0] + out[:-1]
>>> out
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But is there an easier way to achieve the correct output?

Comment: Is the output supposed to have entries for the delimiters or not?  (Your output is inconsistent.)

Comment: You can use just `del out[-1]` or `out.pop()`.

Comment: `The goal is to create an index for up till every [SEP] from left to right, find the [SEP] tokens` - So, are you including the SEP ones when creating the final output? If so, won't the final output be of the same length as the input and hence the final output have 5 `1`s? If not, shouldn't it have 5 `0s` and 4 `1s`?

Comment: Yes the `[SEP]` is included.

Comment: It should be 6 zeros and 5 ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier and vectorized way with NumPy -

```
In [116]: a = np.asarray(tokenized_text)

In [117]: m = a == "[SEP]"

In [118]: m.cumsum()-m
Out[118]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `cumsum`? The output isn't consistent in your question, but such off-by-one errors should be easy to fix.

```
>>> np.cumsum(np.array(tokenized_text) == "[SEP]")
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

For those who don't need/want to use numpy for some reason, there is also `itertools.accumulate`

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(int(elem == '[SEP]') for elem in tokenized_text))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```